# Displaying an array of BufferedImages in a for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of buffered images and im trying to display the images onto frame/jpanel (using a .jar so I dont know if its on a jfame or jpanel) using a for loop. The 1st image is the only one to display correctly. I have tried a repaint and revalidate but it isnt working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the for loop.

```
            //loop through all test images and display
        for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            int xAxis = 1;
            int yAxis = 1;

            imageHandler.displayAnImage(images[i], jvis, xAxis, yAxis, "");

            //if third image in the row then take a new line
            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                yAxis = yAxis + 300;
            }

            //display each image side by side
            xAxis = xAxis + 300;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the code you have right now?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < imagepath.length; i++)
            {
             int xAxis = 1;
             int yAxis = 1;
             
             imageHandler.displayAnImage(allImages[i], jvis, xAxis, yAxis, "");

             //if third image in the row then take a new line
             if(i % 3 == 0)
             {
              yAxis = yAxis + 300;
             }
             
             //display each image side by side
             xAxis = xAxis + 300;
            }

Comment: I dont know how to put it into code format sorry.

Comment: Done, if i do this line imageHandler.displayAnImage(images[i], jvis, xAxis, yAxis, ""); separately not in a for loop it will display the images no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize your xAxis and yAxis variables BEFORE you start your loop, at the start of every loop, you initialize them back to 1, so all images are drawn on the same location.

```
        //loop through all test images and display
    int xAxis = 1;
    int yAxis = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        imageHandler.displayAnImage(images[i], jvis, xAxis, yAxis, "");

        //if third image in the row then take a new line
        if(i % 3 == 0)
        {
            yAxis = yAxis + 300;
        }

        //display each image side by side
        xAxis = xAxis + 300;
    }
```

Comment: omg Im an idiot lol Ive been trying repaint and all these other stuff and it was as simple as that! Sometimes you've just been staring at the same code for too long and a second pair of eyes will solve it. Thank you so much!